# How to format table dynamically within ng-repeat in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a list of items of different types and I would like to display them in a table. 
The items of one type will have two columns and items of another type just one. Any suggestions how to change conditionally the colspan on the <> tag on fly?

```
 <div ng-init="items = [
    {name:'item1', old:1, new:2}, 
    {name:'item2', old:2, new:2},
    {name:'item3', msg: 'message'},
    {name:'item4', old:0, new:2}
  ]">
  <table border=1>    
    <tr  ng-repeat="item in items" >                   
     <th>{{item.name}}</th>
     <td>{{item.old}}</td>  
     <td colspan='2'>{{item.msg}}</td>     
     <td>{{item.new}}</td>      
    </tr>              
 </table>
```

Here is the example to play in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/38LXt/1/

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear. I dont see a `type` field in the items. What is your expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional directives, such as ng-show, to do something like this:

```
<table border=1>    
   <tr  ng-repeat="item in items" >                   
      <th>{{item.name}}</th>
      <td>{{item.old}}</td>  
      <td colspan="2" ng-show="item.type == 'typeA'">{{item.msg}}</td>
      <td ng-show="item.type == 'typeB'">{{item.msgB1}}</td>     
      <td ng-show="item.type == 'typeB'">{{item.msgB2}}</td>          
      <td>{{item.new}}</td>      
   </tr>              
</table>
```

More info about ng-show:

[ngShow directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angShow)

Comment: For completeness `ng-if` too.

Comment: Can you please mark my answer as valid please, to close the subject ?